# Use one Kustomize patch to set environment variables for a deployment and a cron job

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Is there an easy way to share a set of environment variables (coming in from various config maps and secrets) between the same container in a deployment and a cron job?

I'm using Kustomize, but I can't figure out how to approach since with a patch the patch itself would be a bit different depending on if patching a deployment or a cron job.

For example, in my deployment I have something like this:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
    - name: my_app
      env:
        name: SOME_SECRET
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: my_secret
            key: my_key
      envFrom:
        - configmapRef:
            name: some_config_map
```

I'd like to also have this applied to a cron job, but since the YAML schema is different between a deploymnet and a cron job I'm not sure if this is something that is possible/supported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it can be done with Kustomize or not...
But have you considered using helm instead? You can have dedicated templates for deployment and cron job and use the same value for both of their container env field...